# How to filter my table based on this specific date criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014`. Below is an extract of Table `t1`:

```
rownum    RoomID    ArrivalDate    DepartureDate     Name     GuestID
  1         287     2020-01-01      2020-01-09       John      600
  2         451     2020-01-09      2020-01-10       John      600
  3         458     2020-01-09      2020-01-10       John      600
  1         240     2020-03-19      2020-03-21       Alan      112
  2         159     2020-03-21      2020-03-22       Alan      112
  1         400     2020-05-01      2020-05-10       Joe       225
  2         155     2020-06-13      2020-06-18       Joe       225
  1         200     2020-07-01      2020-07-08       Smith     980
  2         544     2020-07-08      2020-07-10       Smith     980
  3         428     2020-09-01      2020-09-05       Smith     980
  ...
```

The problem: I need to filter this table so that the output gives me only those rows of a guest where the difference/s between his ArrivalDate (at rownum 2 or 3 or 4...) and his DepartureDate (at rownum =1) is greater than 0.

To simplify: If we take Guest John, his ArrivalDate for rownum=2 and rownum=3 are both the same as his DepartureDate for rownum=1; therefore I want to exclude him completely in my output. Same for Guest Allan. However, for Guest Smith only where the rownum=2 needs to be excluded.

Note: all guests in this table will have at least a rownum=2 (that is, a minimum of 2 entries).

My expected output:

```
 rownum     RoomID    ArrivalDate     DepartureDate   Name    GuestID
   1         400       2020-05-01      2020-05-10     Joe       225
   2         155       2020-06-13      2020-06-18     Joe       225
   1         200       2020-07-01      2020-07-08     Smith     980         
   3         428       2020-09-01      2020-09-05     Smith     980
```

I am stuck on how to write the logic behind this filter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your current query?

Comment: How about row num = 1, you have to get that as well right?

Comment: @JimMacaulay Yes I need that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here appears to be keeping the first row when you there is a match -- but not including any rows otherwise.  You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when rownum = 1 then departuredate end) over (partition by guestid) as departuredate_1,             
             max(case when rownum <> 1 then arrivaldate end) over (partition by guestid) as arrivaldate_not_1
      from t1 t
     ) t
where (arrivaldate_not_1 > departuredate_1) and
      (rownum = 1 or arrivaldate > departuredate_1);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41ebcf3d615ee8a877b0e1bff156d980) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have missed the alias t after t1. In the fiddle, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query and confirm if this is what you are expecting,

```
select * from table where (ArrivalDate, Name) not in
(select DepartureDate, Name from table);
```

Comment: I get the following error message (with ArrivalDate being underlined): An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Comment: Is your columns names are corret?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #Aridept
(
rownum int,
RoomID int,
ArrivalDate date,
DepartureDate date,
Name varchar(20),
GuestID int
)
insert into #Aridept 
    select  1     ,    287 ,    '2020-01-01',      '2020-01-09',       'John',      600
    union all select 2   ,      451 ,  '2020-01-09',      '2020-01-10','John' ,     600
    union all select 3   ,      458 ,  '2020-01-09',      '2020-01-10','John',      600
    union all select 1   ,      240 ,  '2020-03-19',      '2020-03-21','Alan',      112
    union all select 2   ,      159 ,  '2020-03-21',      '2020-03-22','Alan',      112
    union all select 1   ,      400 ,  '2020-05-01',      '2020-05-10','Joe',        225
    union all select 2   ,      155 ,  '2020-06-13',      '2020-06-18','Joe',       225
    union all select 1   ,      200 ,  '2020-07-01',      '2020-07-08','Smith',     980
    union all select 2   ,      544 ,  '2020-07-08',      '2020-07-10','Smith',     980
    union all select 3   ,      428 ,  '2020-09-01',      '2020-09-05','Smith',     980

--insert into #temp table which have depature date <> arrivedate
    select * into #temp
    from #Aridept a
    where  a.rownum>1 and ArrivalDate not in 
(select DepartureDate from #Aridept b where a.GuestID=b.guestid 
    and rownum=1 )
```

final result query

```
    select * from (
    select * from #Aridept Ari
    where rownum=1 and GuestID in ( select GuestID from #temp)
    union all
    select * from #temp
    )a order by GuestID, rownum
```